# How to have the result of both values when they have the same frequency in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, frequency

I want to have the final result based on the frequency. As shown in the figure, in the red area, V1 shows up more, so of course the final result is "V1".
[image]

It works with the formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A11,MODE(MATCH(A2:A11,A2:A11,0)))
```

But for the blue area, the frequency of V1 and V2 is the same, but I still get the result of "V1" (circled by red).

```
=INDEX(D2:D11,MODE(MATCH(D2:D11,D2:D11,0)))
```

I expect the result "V1 and V2".

Could anyone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Mode() will only return the first value found if two are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MODE.MULT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mode-mult-function-50fd9464-b2ba-4191-b57a-39446689ae8c):

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(A2:A11,MODE.MULT(MATCH(A2:A11,A2:A11,0)))
```

Nest in `TEXTJOIN()` if need be.